# Manipulating a struct in C using functions

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I'm trying to manipulate an dynamically allocated matrix declared as global pointer using functions, for sake of simplicity I'm not gonna paste here the code but I'll provide an equivalent, and probably clearer example

```
structname **variable;

int main()
{
    variable = readfile("filename");
    variable = modify(variable);
    output(variable);
}
```

This looks pretty simple, and input and output works correctly, the problem is that my "modify" function is not making any modification, this is an example of it:

```
structname **modify(structname **p)
{
  swapitems(p[x][y],p[j][z]);
  modifyitem(p[x][y]);
  return p;
}
```

with

```
void swapitems(structname a, structname b)
{
     structname buffer;

     buffer = b;
     b = a;
     a = buffer;
}
```

I guess the problem is that I can't pass the elements to `swapitems` and `modifyitem` like that, how can I modify items using functions like those in the `modify` ?
(of course there are no compiling errors )

Comment: Don't use `void main()`; you'll incur wrath.  It is `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char **argv)`.

Comment: This question has been asked several times. This and other newbie problems like this should be resolved by learning the appropriate section of the C standard or a relevant part of any good C tutorial. This is such a fundamental property of C that it shall be obvious and may not be asked here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are actually passing the structs themselves as arguments, you are simply swapping which stack locations have which struct, and then when you return it does not affect the original array. You could fix this by passing in the actual addresses of the structs in the array:

```
void swapitems(structname* a, structname *b){

    structname buffer;

    buffer = *b;
    *b = *a;
    *a = buffer;
}
```

Then the function call should be

```
swapitems(&p[x][y],&p[j][z]);
```

You should also similarly pass the address of the item you are modifying into `modifyitem`

Comment: or you could just modify the global directly and forget about all that silly OO stuff... and deal with the consequences of highly cross dependant, hard to manage code :)

Comment: thanks that's exactly what I was looking for, I know that I could implement things better, but I've to stick with this

Comment: In case you didn't know, if you found this answer useful you can click the check mark to [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) it.